# Vim: Function to make <CR> exit insert mode unless at end of line

Tags: vim

How do make `<CR>` exit insert mode when the cursor (*) is inside a line? Like:

```
" pressing <CR> should exit insert mode (in either case)
Lorem *ipsum dolor
Lorem ipsum dol*or
```

But also make `<CR>` insert a newline when cursor is at EOL?

```
" pressing <CR> when cursor @ EOL
Lorem ipsum dolor*
Fusce leo quam

" results in
Lorem ipsum dolor
*
Fusce leo quam
```

What does the function look like to make both of these simultaneously possible?

**Rationale:** When maintaining a document I find I do small strokes (i.e. goto word, change it, exit). To me, these strokes are actions I want to 'enter' (like sending a message in a chat window). So having `<CR>` exit insert allows me to keep this mental model when maintaining. On the other hand, `<CR>` is clearly useful when composing. Fortunately, there's enough context to make both simultaneously possible - I just don't have the vimscript skills yet. This will teach me some :)

Comment: Your *rationale* is hardly *rational*.  What will you do when you do want to put a line break in the middle of a line?

Comment: @cptstubings06 `<C-CR>`, which is much rarer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can achieve mappings that depend on some condition with an expression mapping; see `:help :map-expression`. We can check for the cursor at the end of the line via the `col()` function, like this:

```
:inoremap <expr> <CR> col('.') == col('$') ? '<CR>' : '<Esc>'
```